# Could my grinder cut a 3mm steel plate

Tags: steel, metal-cutting, grinder, angle-grinder

I am thinking in building a circular washbasin mounted into a 3mm steel plate. To do it, I need to cut a circle on the plate. I don't have much, just a [cheap 1250w grinder](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07G4VST1K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and the discs that came with it.

I would like to ask you:

- Do you think my grinder will be enough for this? Should I buy new specific discs?
- Do you think my circle will have many imperfections? how could I refine it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are trying to cut a circular hole in the plate to mount the sink in? i.e the hole left in the plate is what you need to have be "good" rather than cutting a circular disk? A disc grinder will do poorly at making a nice hole.

Comment: Would this be a stainless steel plate?

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you. That's it. How would you do it?

Comment: @JimStewart No, just steel. I will paint it after.

Comment: I've cut 3/8" angle iron with one of those grinders... Just need to keep control - strong wrists...

Comment: If I can't cut a perfect hole, I could always put a sink with "two layers" —like the one in the link— so the edge of my cut won't be visible.

https://la.duravit.com/dimg/4203008_web2_tech_draw_2.gif

Comment: Oxy-acetylene cutting torch and a circle jig. Plasma cutter and a circle jig. Hire it cut with a CNC water-jet cutter or CNC plasma cutter or CNC laser cutter. Drill a hole, thread in a blade and saw it out with a bandsaw (assumes blade welding abilities) or jig saw or deep-frame (depends how wide the rim is) hacksaw / fretsaw / jewelers saw.

Comment: Mark the cut out well. Make your cut just shy of the mark. After the shape is cut out come back and grind the edge away until you reach the marked line.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think my grinder will be enough for this? Should I buy new specific discs?

3mm? A number of abrasive wheels can cut that easily.

> Do you think my circle will have many imperfections? how could I refine it?

Depends on the diameter of the circle and how much control you have. Angle grinders have a high [rotational inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) and wouldn't be my first pick for trying to cut a perfect circle. Maybe a smaller tool like a Dremel, or maybe a cutting torch might be better. I would practice on a piece first if you can.

Comment: I agree that a torch would be better but I use thin metal cutting disks all the time for cutting steel. It will take longer than with a torch but it can be done to make a perfect circle make your original cuts and leave the line then go to a thick disk and work your way to the line.+

Comment: Thank you @Machavity . Dremels are quite small and usually doesn't have much power, let's say ~200W. I could consider buying one, but, don't you think it could be not enough for cutting a 3mm steel plate?

Comment: Thank you @EdBeal, it is very useful.

Comment: @riqui The idea behind a Dremel is that it wouldn't be fast, but it would be precise. Again, an angle grinder *could* do the job, it's just harder to control.